# My full stack MERN project works with http but not with https when I deploy to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, deployment, https, mern

I am trying to deploy my full stack MERN project to AWS, and all are good and works (I get everything back from data base) with http! However, when I want to secure the website with https I get this mistake below, please advice me how I can sort it. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)